# How to stop matching if the condition is satisfied?

Tags: regex

Target is to remove patterns (split by '/') with single alphabet, AND if one such pattern appears, then remove the rest right parts.
For example:

```
/modadisi/v/list -> /modadisi
/i/m/videos/tnt  -> null
```

New examples:

```
    /abcd/abcd/abcd/a/abcd -> /abcd/abcd/abcd
    /abcd -> /abcd 
    /abcd/abcd/abcd -> /abcd/abcd/abcd
```

The current regex I use is

```
\/[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

This will match all patterns, like `/modadisi/v/list-> /modadisi/list`. Is it possible to modify the regex to scan from left to right, and stop if condition is matched?

Comment: Do you mean you should extract the part of string immediately followed by 'forward slash, single letter, forward slash' sequence?

Comment: What should it match for something like `/abcd/abcd/abcd/a/abcd`, `/abcd` or `/abcd/abcd/abcd`?

Comment: `^\/[a-zA-Z]{2,}` for the first option, `^(\/[a-zA-Z]{2,})*` for the latter.

Comment: @raina77ow what I want to extract is the part before the sequence you described.. but what you said would inspire me.. let me try.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thx for you reply, I just modified the question and added you examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your new examples, just anchor the pattern to the start of the string using `^`, and put the pattern inside a group that repeats.  The full pattern would be `^(\/[a-zA-Z]{2,})*`.

For the inputs:

```
/modadisi/v/list
/i/m/videos/tnt
/abcd/abcd/abcd/a/abcd
/abcd
/abcd/abcd/abcd
```

it produces:

```
/modadisi
{nothing}
/abcd/abcd/abcd
/abcd
/abcd/abcd/abcd
```

If any of this isn't right, let me know and I will adjust the pattern.

Comment: Sorry, my initial answer produced the wrong output from the examples (the syntax highlighting threw me off).  I've updated it to now *actually* match your examples.

Comment: I noticed that but the regex worked fine for me. So I regarded it as a writing mistake.